# AJAX update for a input block in cloned div

Tags: jquery, ajax, class, clone

I have a div structure as below :

```
<div id="items_block" class="col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div class="item material_item" style="border:1px solid #D9D6D6; padding:8px; background:#E7E3E3; margin:10px 0">
        <div class="form-group ">
          <label for="item_measurement_id" class="col-md-3 control-label">Item Measurement Id</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <select class="required form-control col-md-12 item_measurement" id="item_measurement_id" autocomplete="off" required="true" name="item_measurement_id[]">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select Item</option>           
              <option value="1">pAPER</option><option value="2">KirloskarGREEN</option>
          </select>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a `add new` button which clone the div class `material_item`:

```
$('.add_more_item').click(function(e) {
    item++;
    e.preventDefault();
    var $item = $('.item');
    var $clone = $item.clone(true).removeClass('item'); // Clone item 
    $clone.appendTo("#items_block");
    show_hide_item(item);
});
```

Now I want to update `rate` field when the user changes the `item_measurement_id`. The AJAX is below :

```
$('.item_measurement').change(function(e) {

    var url     = '';
    var data    = '';
    $this = $(this);
    var item_measurement_id = $this.val();
    $parent = $this.parent(); //$('.material_item');

    url     += '{{ route("rest.item_values") }}';
    data    += '&item_measurement_id='+item_measurement_id;

    $.ajax({
        data : data,
        url  : url,
        type : 'get',
        dataType : 'json',

        error : function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        },
        success : function(resp) { console.log(resp.latest_rate);
            $parent.find('.rate').val(resp.latest_rate);
        }
    });
});
```

But I am getting anything in the rate field ! NB : I can see the correct value in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
    $parent = $this.parent(); //$('.material_item');
```

is referencing the immediate parent, which is $('div.col-md-9')

You should use

```
$this.parents('.material_item')
```

to access the element you're trying for.

Also, I would recommend instantiating $this and $parent using var to ensure they are scoped properly, like:

```
var $this = $(this);
var $parent = $this.parent();
```

Comment: Working like charm..Thank you